# A dropdown in the laravel for filtering table data

Tags: laravel, dropdown

I want to know something in Laravel. I want a dropdown for classes so when the user selects any class and press the submit button then the users related to that specific class will be displayed below in the table... Is it possible?

Below is the code I did for getting the data but I want this data to refer to my table in the HTML because there is something more I want and I can't add those things to the ajax table

//My ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('select[name="students_class_id"]').on('change', function() {

            var classID = $(this).val();

            if(classID) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: '/myform/ajax/'+classID,

                    type: "GET",

                    dataType: "json",


                    success:function(data) {

                        var markup = '';

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                             markup += '<tr> <td>' + value.id + '</td> <td>' + value.student_id + '</td> <td>' + value.first_name+ ' '  + value.last_name + '</td> <tr>';

                        });
                        $('table[id="studentsData"]').html(markup);
                    }

                });

            }

        });

    });
```

//Controller

```
 public function index(Request $request){
        $classes = StudentsClass::pluck('class_name', 'id')->all();
        return view('admin.students.attendance.index', compact( 'classes'));
    }

public function mytableAjax($id) {
    $students = Student::where('students_class_id', $id)->get();
    return json_encode($students);
}
```

//My view

```
    <select name="students_class_id" class="form-control" style="width:350px">

        <option value="">--- Select State ---</option>

        @foreach ($classes as $key => $value)

            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>

        @endforeach

    </select>



    <table id="studentsData" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list-search">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Attendance</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="gender">
                            <option>Present</option>
                            <option>Absent</option>
                            <option>Leave</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <a class="fas fa-folder-open btn btn-success float-right mb-4 mr-2"> Save</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible...

Comment: Can You explain pls how it possible without ajax ?

Comment: You need to use ajax.. but no need for any extra library like datatable ... just a simple change event that send a GET request to the controller and get the related data then populate it to the dropdown in the success callback.

Comment: Yes exactly that thing i am doing and i am also getting the desired data but the problem is that data coming to that ajax temporary table which i dont want i just want this data refer to my table in the above html code where i have more things... So is it possible ?

Comment: We need more details, add the relevant code to the original post so we can help.

Comment: Pls read the edited question

Comment: Ok, I see now the code, explain more where in your view you want to place the returned data from the ajax request.

Comment: In the tbody i need some td's for student id , name and the absent, present or leave i have added already

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code that will add the `attendance` column for every row :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="students_class_id"]').on('change', function() {
    var classID = $(this).val();

    if (classID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/myform/ajax/' + classID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var attendance = `<div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="attendance[]">
                            <option>Present</option>
                            <option>Absent</option>
                            <option>Leave</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>`;
          var markup = '';

          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            markup += '<tr> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.id+'" name="id[]">' + value.id + '</td> <td>' + value.student_id + '</td> <td>' + value.first_name + ' ' + value.last_name + '</td> <td> ' + attendance + '</td> <tr>';
          });

          $('#studentsData tbody').html(markup);

          var thead_markup += '<tr> <th>A</th> <th>B</th> <th>C</th> <td>D</th> <tr>';
          $('#studentsData thead').html(thead_markup);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Its the best answer and solved my question but cannot give it vote because my reputation is low :(

Comment: Can you pls give me another example of how to give it some th's for student id name and attendance ?

Comment: Don't worry about the reputation/vote, please try to explain more, do you want to add the `th` columns dynamically too?

Comment: Yes thats what i want

Comment: Adding this var thead_markup += '<tr> <th>A</th> <th>B</th> <th>C</th> <td>D</th> <tr>';
          $('#studentsData thead').html(thead_markup);

Comment: I am getting the same result

Comment: What are you getting? and what are you expecting else?

Comment: Ok i added this at the top and named it as markup .. Now its working perfectly... Another thing i want to know is that now i want this data to save in my database but is it possible to bring data from here and save it in my tables ?

Comment: You need something like a save button to send the data, what I'll suggest is to add hidden inputs for the `id` and the `attendance` with the array names, check my updated answer.

Comment: Now add a button and attach a click event to it that will get the inputs values and send them to an action in your controller where you'll loop through them and update your DB.

Comment: Ok I get it but i have already one button in the above html. What can i do with that ?

Comment: Attach a click event to it, then get all the values you want with `var data = $('#studentsData').find('select, input').serialize();` and send them as the data properties in the post request to your controller action.

Comment: Ok sir thank you so much for your help.. It really help me out and i was struggling for it for almost 4 days . Stay blessed :)

Comment: I'm here for any help. you could find my personal email in the profile, keep the work up, and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your code, if you are using ajax datatables api then here is a similar example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Reference: datatables.net multi filter select

If you are not using datatables api and do not want ajax then use below code and change according to your need:

```
 $("#selectDropdown").on("change", function () {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
                        if (index != 0) {

                            $row = $(this);

                            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

                            if (id.indexOf(value) != 0) {
                                $(this).hide();
                            }
                            else {
                                $(this).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Comment: I am not using ajax datatables but i am getting some data using ajax code in the form of json but i dont want using ajax i want to do it without ajax

Comment: Because using ajax i have some problems during saving data to my tables thats why i want to do in the laravel

Comment: Ok i think the below code will help me but can you explain what this code will do ? and do i need some changes in the controller ?

Comment: you said you don't want an ajax right?  so add student class column to your table which obviousely change a bit of your code in your controller for example join student table with student class table to get student class name, then use my code. note: currently it is searching first column.